# How do I work with logman results using powershell cmdlets?

Tags: powershell, logman

I am trying to filter the results of the logman command using powershell. I’ve tried to select a single property, filter using where-object, but it seems like the results from logman (stored in an array) are not accessible via their properties. Here are some commands I have tried so far:

```bsh
logman -ets query #returns result

logman -ets query | select-object #returns result

logman -ets query | select-object -first 10 -Property Status #nothing

logman -ets | where-object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} #nothing

logman -ets | where-object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} #nothing

logman -ets | where-object {$_.Status -gt "R"} -debug #nothing
```

I am hoping to filter out just those sessions that pertain to my local service fabric emulator so I can get a handle on where my various service fabric logs are stored.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You cannot use Select-Object because you don't have any object. You will have to parse the text output logman produces.

Comment: What does the output look like?

Comment: The output of the command appears like this:  (I'm not sure how to paste code in a comment - so this is garbled... The output is a header row, followed by dashes, followed by what appears to be columns of data, one column for each header.


`
Data Collector Set                      Type                          Status
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Circular Kernel Context Logger          Trace                         Running 
AppModel                                Trace                         Running 
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`logman`, being an "external" command (one implemented as a .EXE file, rather than a PowerShell cmdlet), does not generate Objects within the meaning of the term in PowerShell. Instead, it generates a text stream, which you will have to parse. From the looks of it, the status is the last eight characters of the line, so you'll need to do something like

```bsh
logman -ets query | Where-Object {-join $_[-8..-1] -eq "Running "}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying. I was thrown off because the "text" output of the logman exe command appears to be that which would be outputted by a normal powersell command. So, I incorrectly assumed it was.

With this knowledge, I should be able to write a wrapper for this in c# which preforms the action in a normal "powershell" way. 

Thank you!